# getting remote ip address in connectionless server

Tags: java, netty

Currently I've made a connectionless server and I'd like to know a remote ip address of each udp packet.

To do so, I use

```
addr = ((InetSocketAddress)ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress()).getAddress();
```

in my channel handler such as

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent ev) throws Exception
```

But *NullPointerException* comes out. In my guess, the channel has been closed after receiving each udp packet because of connectionless channel.

How can I know it in this case?

Thanks~

Answer (score 5):

I noticed the same thing, which is that the channel will not provide the remote address, but when you think about it, it's not the channel (or the DatagramSocket it wraps) that even knows about the remote address, but the Datagram itself does, which is the payload. The payload is delivered in a netty [MessageEvent](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/MessageEvent.html), and if you call [MessageEvent.getRemoteAddress()](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/MessageEvent.html#getRemoteAddress%28%29), it returns what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear (at least to me) what the ChannelHandlerContext class is that you are referencing.

If you use a DatagramSocket[1], you can use the receive[1] method to read UDP packets. As documented in the receive method[2], the DatagramPacket[3] will have the sender's ip address and port number.

[1] - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html
[2] - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)
[3] - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html

Comment: It does not appear that the NIO DatagramChannel provides this information.        http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html

Comment: He's actually asking about Netty, not about NIO.